# Is it possible to merge several attribute values and show it under single attribute name in the filtering?

Tags: product-attribute, filter, attribute-set

We sell shoes online and have EUR, UK and US sizes. In the filters this appears very messy and also misleading as if you filter by UK11, the shoes that come in a European sizes would not be showing, even though there is a EUR 45 that would be the equivalent.

Is it possible to have one filtering option for, for example "UK 11/US 12/EUR 45" instead of having one for UK 11, one for US12 and one for EUR45?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to combine separate attributes and filter them as one out-of-box. You can make three size attributes appear as `UK 11/US 12/EUR 45` and have that one filter actually filter three attributes, but this is slow, clunky, and just a bad design overall.

The simplest method is to unify the different size attributes you have into one and give it options that include all three sizes.

The other option is give different size labels for different website for your size attribute, so that they will appear in different units depending on the site you're on. This would be my pick.